# Set ACF on order during checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to populate a field on an order with options set by the user during checkout, on our checkout form.

```
function populate_custom_field_value( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['custom_field_value'] ) ) {
        update_field( 'field_xxxxxxxxxxxxx', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_field_value']), $order_id );
    }
}
```

My html select component is being inserted correctly, with the values defined in ACF, but it’s not setting the field on the order.
Can anyone see what I’m missing here?

Solved, thanks :)

Comment: Did you validate that the filter is run first, before checking if the update is correct? You could exit; wp_die or write to an error_log to check..

Comment: You can read the function options here - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Comment: @QStudio
It's firing populate_custom_field_value and it's getting inside the if statement :) my update_field looks to be doing what the documentation says. Or you don't think so?

Comment: I think the best way to know if it's working is if the data is saved, or an error is returned - if both are good, then good - if not.. then you need you dig in deeper to find the problem..